# Fixing and replacing Google's icons in Windows 10

Tags: windows, google-chrome, icons, registry

I remember having fixed this by finding a value in the registry that appeared to be overriding the how the images were shown, but I can't remember where it was, nor the source that showed me. I'm getting annoyed again at having images such as these show up when I pin them to my Windows 10 Pro Start Menu:

[image]

I know that there was a fix for this, but for the life of me, I can't seem to remember what it was.

As a note, I had tried tweaking with the shortcuts found in *C:\Users[me]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Chrome Apps*
to no avail. I swear the fix was related to something simple in the registry, but I can't place my mind on what it was. Any suggestions?